# Core data getting locked with multi threading (_objectStoreLockCount > 1)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, core-data

I am finding a hard time in fixing a core data DB lock situation (_objectStoreLockCount count is > 1 when I run in debug mode).

Below is the architecture of my application (MAC OSX):

1. I am using 2 NSOperationQueue to perform some activities. Each queue having some 20 activities running in parallel.
2. Once these activities are done, each one of them put result data in another NSOperationQueue which has a maximum Concurrent Operation Count set to 1.
3. The result operation queue then puts the data in the core data.
4. There are 2 other threads running. One of which is reading the data from core data. Another one, based on some logic, is updating the existing records in the core data.
5. For core data handling, I have created a subclass of NSObject having 3 objects. Each object has it own NSManagedObjectContext - 1 for reading data, 1 for writing new records and 1 for updating existing records. I am updating the read managed object context whenever there is a change in write managed object context. All three MOCs have common persistent store co-ordinator.
6. The application is supposed to run 24*7 All the above code is bound to repeat

**Issue: When I run my application it randomly hangs or locks the DB. It reaches to this state any random times  - 2 hours, 10 hours not defined...**

I am attaching the core data handling part of the application. Please let me know if I am missing something in core data handling:

```
@implementation MyAppDataRepository

@synthesize persistentStoreCoordinator = _persistentStoreCoordinator;
@synthesize managedObjectModel = _managedObjectModel;
@synthesize writeManagedObjectContext = _writeManagedObjectContext;
@synthesize readManagedObjectContext = _readManagedObjectContext;
@synthesize updateManagedObjectContext = _updateManagedObjectContext;

static  MyAppDataRepository *sharedMyAppWriteDataRepository = nil;
static  MyAppDataRepository *sharedMyAppReadDataRepository = nil;
static  MyAppDataRepository *sharedMyAppupdateDataRepository = nil;

+ (MyAppDataRepository *)sharedMyAppWriteDataRepositoryMyApp
{
    static dispatch_once_t pred = 0;
    dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
        sharedMyAppWriteDataRepository = [[self alloc] init];
        [sharedMyAppWriteDataRepository persistentStoreCoordinator];
        [sharedMyAppWriteDataRepository writeManagedObjectContext];
    });

    return sharedMyAppWriteDataRepository;
}

+ (MyAppDataRepository *)sharedMyAppReadDataRepositoryMyApp
{
    static dispatch_once_t pred = 0;
    dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
        sharedMyAppReadDataRepository = [[self alloc] init]; // or some other init method
        [sharedMyAppReadDataRepository persistentStoreCoordinator];
        [sharedMyAppReadDataRepository readManagedObjectContext];
    });

    return sharedMyAppReadDataRepository;
}


+ (MyAppDataRepository *)sharedMyAppupdateDataRepositoryMyApp
{
    static dispatch_once_t pred = 0;
    dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
        sharedMyAppupdateDataRepository = [[self alloc] init]; // or some other init method
        [sharedMyAppupdateDataRepository persistentStoreCoordinator];
        [sharedMyAppupdateDataRepository  updateManagedObjectContext];
    });

    return sharedMyAppupdateDataRepository;
}


-(id)init {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        if (!self.writeManagedObjectContext) {
            MyAppLOG(@"Core data cannot be initiated");
        }
    }
    return  self;
}

// Returns the directory the application uses to store the Core Data store file. This code uses a directory named "com.apple.retail.MyApp" in the user's Application Support directory.
- (NSURL *)applicationFilesDirectory
{
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSURL *appSupportURL = [[fileManager URLsForDirectory:NSApplicationSupportDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
    return [appSupportURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"com.apple.retail.MyApp"];
}

// Creates if necessary and returns the managed object model for the application.
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel
{
    if (_managedObjectModel) {
        return _managedObjectModel;
    }

    NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"MyApp" withExtension:@"momd"];
    _managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
    return _managedObjectModel;
}

// Returns the persistent store coordinator for the application. This implementation creates and return a coordinator, having added the store for the application to it. (The directory for the store is created, if necessary.)
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
    if (_persistentStoreCoordinator) {
        return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    NSManagedObjectModel *mom = [self managedObjectModel];
    if (!mom) {
        MyAppLOG(@"%@:%@ No model to generate a store from", [self class], NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
        return nil;
    }

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSURL *applicationFilesDirectory = [self applicationFilesDirectory];
    NSError *error = nil;

    NSDictionary *properties = [applicationFilesDirectory resourceValuesForKeys:@[NSURLIsDirectoryKey] error:&error];

    if (!properties) {
        BOOL ok = NO;
        if ([error code] == NSFileReadNoSuchFileError) {
            ok = [fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:[applicationFilesDirectory path] withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&error];
        }
        if (!ok) {
            [[NSApplication sharedApplication] presentError:error];
            return nil;
        }
    } else {
        if (![properties[NSURLIsDirectoryKey] boolValue]) {
            // Customize and localize this error.
            NSString *failureDescription = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Expected a folder to store application data, found a file (%@).", [applicationFilesDirectory path]];

            NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
            [dict setValue:failureDescription forKey:NSLocalizedDescriptionKey];
            error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN" code:101 userInfo:dict];

            [[NSApplication sharedApplication] presentError:error];
            return nil;
        }
    }

    //Support for automatic migration of core data
    NSMutableDictionary *optionsDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [optionsDictionary setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]
                          forKey:NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption];
    [optionsDictionary setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption];

    NSURL *url = [applicationFilesDirectory URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyApp.sqlite"];
    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:mom];
    if (![coordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:url options:optionsDictionary error:&error]) {
        [[NSApplication sharedApplication] presentError:error];
        return nil;
    }
    _persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator;

    return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
}


// Returns the managed object context for the application (which is already bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.)
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)writeManagedObjectContext {
    if (_writeManagedObjectContext) {
        return _writeManagedObjectContext;
    }

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (!coordinator) {
        NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        [dict setValue:@"Failed to initialize the store" forKey:NSLocalizedDescriptionKey];
        [dict setValue:@"There was an error building up the data file." forKey:NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey];
        NSError *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN" code:9999 userInfo:dict];
        [[NSApplication sharedApplication] presentError:error];
        return nil;
    }
    _writeManagedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
    [_writeManagedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];

    return _writeManagedObjectContext;
}


- (NSManagedObjectContext *)readManagedObjectContext {
    if (_readManagedObjectContext) {
        return _readManagedObjectContext;
    }

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (!coordinator) {
        NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        [dict setValue:@"Failed to initialize the store" forKey:NSLocalizedDescriptionKey];
        [dict setValue:@"There was an error building up the data file." forKey:NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey];
        NSError *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN" code:9999 userInfo:dict];
        [[NSApplication sharedApplication] presentError:error];
        return nil;
    }
    _readManagedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
    [_readManagedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];

    return _readManagedObjectContext;
}


- (NSManagedObjectContext *)updateManagedObjectContext {
    if (_updateManagedObjectContext) {
        return _updateManagedObjectContext;
    }

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (!coordinator) {
        NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        [dict setValue:@"Failed to initialize the store" forKey:NSLocalizedDescriptionKey];
        [dict setValue:@"There was an error building up the data file." forKey:NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey];
        NSError *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN" code:9999 userInfo:dict];
        [[NSApplication sharedApplication] presentError:error];
        return nil;
    }
    _updateManagedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
    [_updateManagedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];

    return _updateManagedObjectContext;
}


// Returns the NSUndoManager for the application. In this case, the manager returned is that of the managed object context for the application.
- (NSUndoManager *)windowWillReturnUndoManager:(NSWindow *)window {
    return [[self writeManagedObjectContext] undoManager];
}

// Performs the save action for the application, which is to send the save: message to the application's managed object context. Any encountered errors are presented to the user.
- (IBAction)saveAction:(id)sender
{
    NSError *error = nil;

    if (![[self writeManagedObjectContext] commitEditing]) {
        MyAppLOG(@"%@:%@ unable to commit editing before saving", [self class], NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
    }

    if (![[self writeManagedObjectContext] save:&error]) {
        [[NSApplication sharedApplication] presentError:error];
    }
}


- (BOOL)saveDataInDatabase:(NSManagedObjectContext *)iContext {
    BOOL dataSavedSuccessfully = YES;

    NSError *error = nil;

    if (![iContext commitEditing]) {
        MyAppLOG(@"%@:%@ unable to commit editing before saving", [self class], NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
    }

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleDidSaveNotification:) name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification object:iContext];


    if (![iContext save:&error]) {
        dataSavedSuccessfully = NO;
        [[NSApplication sharedApplication] presentError:error];
    }

    // unregister from notification
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification object:iContext];

    return dataSavedSuccessfully;
}


// Merge the changes from write managed object context to read managed object context
- (void)handleDidSaveNotification:(NSNotification *)iNotification {
    [[MyAppDataRepository sharedMyAppReadDataRepository].readManagedObjectContext mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:iNotification];
}


- (NSApplicationTerminateReply)applicationShouldTerminate:(NSApplication *)sender
{
    // Save changes in the application's managed object context before the application terminates.

    if (!_writeManagedObjectContext) {
        return NSTerminateNow;
    }

    if (![[self writeManagedObjectContext] commitEditing]) {
        MyAppLOG(@"%@:%@ unable to commit editing to terminate", [self class], NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
        return NSTerminateCancel;
    }

    if (![[self writeManagedObjectContext] hasChanges]) {
        return NSTerminateNow;
    }

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![[self writeManagedObjectContext] save:&error]) {

        // Customize this code block to include application-specific recovery steps.
        BOOL result = [sender presentError:error];
        if (result) {
            return NSTerminateCancel;
        }

        NSString *question = NSLocalizedString(@"Could not save changes while quitting. Quit anyway?", @"Quit without saves error question message");
        NSString *info = NSLocalizedString(@"Quitting now will lose any changes you have made since the last successful save", @"Quit without saves error question info");
        NSString *quitButton = NSLocalizedString(@"Quit anyway", @"Quit anyway button title");
        NSString *cancelButton = NSLocalizedString(@"Cancel", @"Cancel button title");
        NSAlert *alert = [[NSAlert alloc] init];
        [alert setMessageText:question];
        [alert setInformativeText:info];
        [alert addButtonWithTitle:quitButton];
        [alert addButtonWithTitle:cancelButton];

        NSInteger answer = [alert runModal];

        if (answer == NSAlertAlternateReturn) {
            return NSTerminateCancel;
        }
    }

    return NSTerminateNow;
}


- (void)insertTestResults:(NSArray *)iTestData withUpdateFlag:(int)iUpdateFlag withDiscardDlag:(int)iDiscardFlag {
    NSManagedObjectContext *aWriteManagedObjContext = [[MyAppDataRepository sharedMyAppWriteDataRepositoryMyApp] writeManagedObjectContext];

    NSManagedObject *aTestResults;
    NSMutableArray *aTestIDArray=[NSMutableArray array];

    for (MyAppTestResultsModel *iTestResultsData in iTestData) {
        NSString *aTestType=[iTestResultsData valueForKey:kMyAppTestType];

        if ([aTestType isEqualToString:kMyAppTest1Type]) {
            aTestResults=[NSEntityDescription
                          insertNewObjectForEntityForName:kMyAppTest1ResultsEntity
                          inManagedObjectContext:aWriteManagedObjContext];
        } else if ([aTestType isEqualToString:kMyAppTest2Type]) {
            aTestResults=[NSEntityDescription
                          insertNewObjectForEntityForName:kMyAppTest2ResultsEntity
                          inManagedObjectContext:aWriteManagedObjContext];
        } else if ([aTestType isEqualToString:kMyAppTest3Type]) {
            aTestResults=[NSEntityDescription
                          insertNewObjectForEntityForName:kMyAppTest3ResultsEntity
                          inManagedObjectContext:aWriteManagedObjContext];
        } else if ([aTestType isEqualToString:kMyAppTest4Type]) {
            aTestResults=[NSEntityDescription
                          insertNewObjectForEntityForName:kMyAppTest4ResultsEntity
                          inManagedObjectContext:aWriteManagedObjContext];
        }

        NSError *anError=nil;
        if (![self saveDataInDatabase:aWriteManagedObjContext]) {
            MyAppLOG(@"Cannot Save!: %@", [anError localizedDescription]);
        }
        else
        {
            // Post the saved Message to the main window
            NSString *aLog = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\n \n%@ Test Results Saved \n %@",[iTestResultsData valueForKey:kMyAppTestType], aTestResults];
            MyAppLOG(@"%@",aLog);
            MyAppINFOLOG(@"Saved test results (in client DB) for Test ID = %@ Test Type = %@ App ID = %@ Network = %@ Status = %@", [iTestResultsData valueForKey:kMyAppTestID], [iTestResultsData valueForKey:kMyAppTestType], [iTestResultsData valueForKey:kMyAppAppIDAttribute], [iTestResultsData valueForKey:kMyAppTestNetwork], [iTestResultsData valueForKey:kMyAppTestStatusAttribute]);

            [aTestIDArray addObject:[aTestResults valueForKey:kMyAppTestIDAttribute]];

            // Update the isReadyToFlag
            if (iUpdateFlag == 1)
                [MyAppFetchTestConfigDetails updateReadyToRunForTestID:[NSArray arrayWithArray:aTestIDArray] withInt:iUpdateFlag];
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the operation queue implementation for Thread 2 (that has been filled by multiple threads):

```
@implementation MyAppSaveTestResultController

- (id)init {
    if ((self = [super init]) != nil) {
        self.queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
        [self.queue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:1];
    }
    return self;
}

+ (MyAppSaveTestResultController *)sharedSaveResultsController {
    static dispatch_once_t pred = 0;
    dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
        sharedSaveResultsController = [[self alloc] init]; // or some other init method
    });
    return sharedSaveResultsController;
}

- (void)startSaveOperation {
    MyAppSaveTestResultsOperation *aSaveOperation = [[MyAppSaveTestResultsOperation alloc] initWithTestResults:self.testResults updateFlag:self.updateFlag andDiscardDlag:self.discardFlag];
    [self.queue addOperation:aSaveOperation];

}


@implementation MySaveTestResultsOperation

- (id)initWithTestResults:(NSArray *)iTestData updateFlag:(int)iUpdateFlag andDiscardDlag:(int)iDiscardFlag {
    if ((self = [super init]) != nil)
    {
        self.testResults = iTestData;
        self.updateFlag = iUpdateFlag;
        self.discardFlag = iDiscardFlag;
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)start {
    if (![NSThread isMainThread])
    {
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(start) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
        return;
    }

    // Check for cancellation
    if ([self isCancelled]) {
        [self completeOperation];
        return;
    }

    // Executing
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
    executing = YES;
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];

    // Begin
    [self beginOperation];
}

- (void)beginOperation {
    @try {
        [[MyAppDataRepository sharedMyAppWriteDataRepository] insertTestResults:results withUpdateFlag:self.updateFlag withDiscardDlag:self.discardFlag];
        [self completeOperation];
    } @catch(NSException * e) {
    }
}
```

Below piece of code is called from all the activity threads (as many as 20 concurrent threads) that fill in the data into MyAppSaveTestResultController:

```
MyAppSaveTestResultController *aSaveTestResultController = [MyAppSaveTestResultController sharedSaveResultsController];
    [aSaveTestResultController saveTestResults:[NSArray arrayWithObject:data] updateFlag:[[NSNumber numberWithBool:[aBlockSelf checkPendingTestsForTestID:anID]] intValue] discardFlag:0];
    [aSaveTestResultController startSaveOperation];
```

Comment: I don't see any interaction with the `NSOperationQueues` here, that's probably where you problem is. You should not be creating separate `NSManagedObjectContext`s for reading and writing, the MOCs job is to arbitrate that by themselves; your problem is you need at least one MOC *per thread*.  Running 20 parallel activities on a persistent store will require 20 MOCs, references to MOCs and their respective managed objects cannot cross thread boundaries.

Comment: I did not put my operation queue code here to not mess up with the space. But essentially I am calling "insertTestResults" mentioned above from the operation queue which is managed one operation at a time. Additionally, I am using GCD to run my update thread which is using the update MOC. Do you mean I have to initialize MOC from both these places (instead of fixing it to write & update MOC)?

Comment: You can do reading, updating, and inserting with a single `NSManagedObjectContext`, you just can't call the same managed object context from two different threads.  Even if an MOC to just doing reads, it cannot be called upon by more than one thread at a time -- your update and read operations must either have their own MOCs per operation, or have exclusive access to an MOC that cannot be interrupted.

Are you sure you want to do this with `CoreData`?  It seems like if you need this kind of concurrency and uptime you might be better off with just sqlite or a proper DB server.

Comment: I am using SQLITE with core data. As I mentioned with above 3 MOCs I am using NSOperation queue with 1 operation at a time making sure that at one time only one thread is using them. Is that not sufficient? Please enlighten me.

Comment: What are the "2 other threads running" doing?  Are they interacting with MOCs?

Comment: Thread 1 - Using read MOC - This is called every 1 min to read data from the Core Data. Thread 2 - Using write MOC - This is a NSOperation queue with 1 operation at a time. This is writing new records in the database. This queue is filled up by as many as 20 different threads. Thread 3 - Using update MOC - This is called every 1 min and updating the existing records in the DB.

Comment: Are threads one and three limited to one concurrent operation as well?  I'm having trouble understanding how an operation queue can have one operation at a time but be "filled up by as many as 20 threads."  One concurrent operation means one thread.

Comment: Thread 1 and 3 are also one operation at a time. For Thread 2, I have edited my question to put on more details. Please advise.

Comment: Are logging your `@catch` block? you should always call `completeOperation`, or your queue will get clogged. In addition, why are you executing your operations on the main thread?

Comment: Yeah. I just noticed that and have made them executed on parallel thread. I am keeping an eye if this solves the issue.

Comment: If you execute the operations in a thread other than the main thread in your current configuration you will break the context thread confinement as the queue will not always use the same thread for each operation. why aren't you using private queues? (`[context performBlock:...]`)

Comment: So, this queue can have as many as 60 operations (may be more) in it and it is running concurrently. Is it a good idea to use [context performBlock:...] in that case?